# angularjs http remote api failing to load

Tags: angularjs, api, http, get

Could someone please run this code on their localhost, I have been trying to figure out why the first GET returns an empty response and the second GET returns expected response but indicates its malformed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" ng-app="app">
<body>
  <div ng-controller="mainController"></div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.baseUrl = "http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?action=echo&encoding=json&foo=bar";
    //$scope.baseUrl = 'http://www.iNorthwind.com/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers';

    // Works but no response content
    $http({method: 'GET', url: $scope.baseUrl})
     .success(function(data,status){
      console.log( data);
     });

    // Works but console states malformed jsonp, but has response content.      
   $http({method: 'jsonp', url: $scope.baseUrl + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'})
     .success(function(data,status){
      console.log( data);
    });   
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second one you have a mismatched quotation after CALLBACK

```
   $http({method: 'jsonp', url: $scope.baseUrl + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"})
     .success(function(data,status){
      console.log( data);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that cured it. Maybe I should sleep more and code a little less at night.